# Image wont fit picturebox

Tags: vb.net, image-processing

I have a winforms program that scans a document and saves it to a file, It then opens another form and loads a cropped portion of the image into a picturebox but the image does not fill the picturebox.

The code that does this is as follows:

```
Public Function Crop() As Image

    ' Function to rotate and crop the scanned image to speed up barcode reading

    Dim Mystream As New FileStream(TempRoot & StrFileName & Exten, FileMode.Open)
    Dim bitmap1 As New Bitmap(Mystream)
    imageAttr1.SetGamma(2.2F)

    ' Rotates and crops the scanned document

    Try

        If bitmap1 IsNot Nothing Then
            bitmap1.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone)
        End If

        cropX = 1500
        cropY = 200
        cropWidth = 1100
        cropHeight = 550

        ' Sets a rectangle to display the area of the source image

        rect = New Rectangle(cropX, cropY, cropWidth, cropHeight)

        ' Create a new bitmap with the width and height values specified by cropWidth and cropHeight.

        cropBitmap = New Bitmap(cropWidth, cropHeight)

        ' Creates a new Graphics object that will draw on the cropBitmap

        g = Graphics.FromImage(cropBitmap)

        ' Draws the portion of the image that you supplied cropping values for.

        g.DrawImage(bitmap1, 0, 0, rect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
        g.DrawImage(cropBitmap, rect, 0, 0, OKTickets.ImgTicket.Width, OKTickets.ImgTicket.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imageAttr1)

    Catch ex As System.IO.FileNotFoundException

        MessageBox.Show("There was an error. Check the path to the bitmap.")

    End Try

    Mystream.Close()

    Return cropBitmap

End Function
```

I have a label on the form which shows the width & height of the image and the width and height of the picturebox.

The size of the picturebox is width = 1100 & height = 550.

The image shows the same size but it only fills the top left hand quarter of the picturebox.

I have tried setting the picturebox size mode to all the settings but it makes no difference to the image atall.

Can anyone see why it isn't filling the picturebox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are experiencing a scaling issue.
You indicate that the source image is scanned in.  Most likely the image is scanned at a high resolution.  When you create a new `Bitmap`, its default resolution is 96 x 96.

From the `Remarks` section of the [DrawImage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142041(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks) method you are using.

> An Image stores a value for pixel width and a value for horizontal resolution (dots per inch). The physical width, measured in inches, of an image is the pixel width divided by the horizontal resolution. For example, an image with a pixel width of 360 and a horizontal resolution of 72 dots per inch has a physical width of 5 inches. Similar remarks apply to pixel height and physical height.
>
> This method draws a portion of an image using its physical size, so
>   the image portion will have its correct size in inches regardless of
>   the resolution (dots per inch) of the display device. For example,
>   suppose an image portion has a pixel width of 216 and a horizontal
>   resolution of 72 dots per inch. If you call this method to draw that
>   image portion on a device that has a resolution of 96 dots per inch,
>   the pixel width of the rendered image portion will be (216/72)*96 =
>   288.

You have two Options to resolve the issue.

1. You can set the resolution of `cropBitmap` to match the source image.

   cropBitmap.SetResolution(bitmap1.HorizontalResolution, bitmap1.VerticalResolution)
2. Use the [DrawImageUnscaled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7fktfzk(v=vs.110).aspx) Method.

   g.DrawImageUnscaled(bitmap1, -rect.Left, -rect.Top, 0, 0)